# Answer does not make sense to me

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For each natural number n, let $A_n =\{0,1,2,3,...,n\}$. Find

$$\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i = \{0\} \cup \mathbb{N}$$

and

$$\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i = \{0,1\}$$

Those answers don't make sense to me. I somewhat understand union answer better than the intersection answer.

For the intersection, I understand it to mean
$A_1 = \{0\}$
$A_2 = \{0,1\}$
$A_3 = \{0,1,2\}$

and so on

Maybe I don't know the definition of each well enough. Some examples or explanation would go a long way.

Comment: No, $A_1=\{0,1\}$.  You should specify $\mathbb N=\{1,2,\dots\}$, because sometimes people write $\mathbb N$ for $\{0,1,2\dots\}$

Comment: That is true J. W.  Tanner. The book specified $ \mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,...\}$. That is why I was confused. If we include 0 in the natural numbers, then it makes sense for $A_1$ to have 0 and 1 as elements. Thank you all for clearing up my confusion

Comment: The question makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's list out some of these sets:
\begin{align*}
A_1 &= \{0,1\} \\
A_2 &= \{0,1,2\} \\
A_3 &= \{0,1,2,3\} \\
A_4 &= \{0,1,2,3,4\} \\
& \vdots \\
A_k &= \{0,1,2,3,4, \ldots, k\} 
\end{align*}
The union of the $A_i$, I claim, is $\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$. We'll show this by dual inclusion. Certainly, for each $i \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $A_i \subset \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$, so $\bigcup\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i \subset \mathbb{N}$. Furthermore, given any $x \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$, I can find you a set that $x$ belongs to. We see that if $x = 0$, then $x$ is in any of the $A_i$, say $A_1$, and if $x > 0$, then $x \in A_x$; in fact, we have $x \in A_n$ for any $n > x$. So $\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} \subset \bigcup\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i$, hence $\bigcup\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i = \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$.

Now, onward to the intersection. First, notice that for any $j$, we have $\bigcap\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i \subset A_j$. Why? Well, by definition, if $x \in \bigcap\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i$, then $x \in A_i$ for every $i$. In particular, we can limit the intersection immediately to at most two elements by noticing that $\bigcap\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i \subset A_1 = \{0,1\}$. Furthermore, we see that every $A_k$ contains both $0$ and $1$ definitionally, so $\bigcap\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i = A_1 = \{0,1\}$.

Comment: I really liked your way of explaining. One last question. Why does $A_1$ contain 0 and 1?

Comment: The definition of $A_n$ is that it contains all of the integers between $0$ and $1$, inclusive. If $n = 1$, this is exactly the set $\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

In words $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N} A_i$ is the set of elements which are in $A_i$ for some $i$. This is exactly $0\cup\mathbb N$.

$\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb N} A_i$ is the set of elements which are in $A_i$ for all $i$, which is exactly $\{0,1\}$. One way to see this is that since $A_1$ is the smallest of all the $A_i$ ($A_1$ is contained in all $A_i$), we have $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb N} A_i = A_1 = \{0,1\}$.

Comment: May be I am interpreting the subindeces wrong.  What would $A_2$ and $A_3$ look like?

Comment: $A_2=\{0,1,2\}, A_3=\{0,1,2,3\},$ etc.

Comment: I think I see now. Each $A_i$ is it's own set which is constructed from  how $A_n$ was defined. And then we take a look at the union and intersection of those $A_i's$ as individual sets on their own. But why must $A_1$ get the 0 and 1?

Comment: Maybe it is the use of the $i$ and the $n$ that is confusing. These are just variable names. So maybe forget about the $n$. The definition of $A_i$ is $$A_i=\{0,1,2,\dots,i\}$$ for each $i$. So in particular when $i=1$, plug in $i=1$ in the above to get $A_1 =\{0,1\}$.